# Changing old bathroom receptacle to gfci

Tags: electrical

The new gfci receptacle has only 1 set of connections while my old receptacle has 2 hot wires and 1 white. How to connect?

Comment: Maybe I mis read the first time you only have 2 hot and 1 white. With out more information we really can’t be sure how things are wired. In any case the wiring is not to code.

Comment: I gather they are wires. I expect there's also a light switch here.  only 1 neutral because it is pigtailed.

Answer (score 2):

Most GFCI devices will take 2 wires underneath one screw.  You loosen the screw, then insert the 2 wires in 2 back-connect holes that are under /next to the screw.  Then, you tighten the screw firmly to clamp the wires.

If I had one that didn't t have the feature, I would either take it back and exchange for one that did, or use a different technique called a **pigtail**.  However, a pigtail requires that you have spare wires and wirenuts and a stripper.

You may note that there is a warning label on the GFCI that says, "Do not use. For wizards only." or words to that effect.  There are in fact screws under that sticker, but it's a big mistake to use them here.  So leave that sticker be.

Answer (score 0):

There should be line and load connections on your receptacle if not you will need to get some wire nuts, and some short pieces of the same gauge wires. Tie the 2 whites with a short piece of wire together then put that on the silver / or neutral contact. Do the same with the 2 blacks and tie that to the hot or normally brass screw. If you gave a ground you can pigtail those also and connect to the green screw. That should do it. If you need more info we would need a photo of the back of your GFCI and the existing wiring.

Comment: She has 3 wires. You can't mean use one LOAD terminal and not the other.

Comment: I thought she was saying 2 cables and pigtailing the line to the outlet not using the load at all